# How can I get this character "ā" to show up in the title on my html page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

My html page has the correct encoding as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And in the pages of my website this character is showing up correctly "ā"

However in the title it is not showing up.

I only get z-go instead of Zāgo

I am on Rails 2.3.2.

Comment: It sounds like the font your browser is using to render the title doesn't contain the character. There isn't anything you can do about that (as an author).

Comment: I have tried it on other browsers and it also does not show.

Comment: Most browsers on most platforms use a standard toolkit to render the browser chome. The title bar font will usually be determined by the desktop preferences and not the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The title bar of the application is displayed by the operating system, not by the browser itself. So the system may not have the `ā` present in the font used for the title bar. Check your settings.

Comment: Its on Heroku and I asked their tech support but they are also perplexed.

Answer (score 0):

instead of typing the character directly enter `&#257;`
Check encoding on and around instances described in your answer.

Comment: The document is, according to the question, marked with the correct encoding. So using a character reference shouldn't have any effect (beyond making the document consist of more bytes). You also forgot the terminating semi-colon.

Comment: I thought and still maybe correct that by the correct encoding he simply declared utf 8. He didnt specify whether he had entered the unicode character code already. Which is why i was suggesting to do so.

Comment: The question explicitly states that elsewhere in the document the character is being rendered correctly so it can't be an encoding issue.

Comment: Hence, the places its not showing up correctly in some places could be an encoding issue, where it might be wrong in some places for whatever reason. Its likely to be an encoding problem around the character in the places its not showing up correctly

Comment: It is really very difficult to get a character mis-encoded in just some parts of a document.

Comment: Agreed. But it definitely is a possibility. And it is a quick avenue he could explore. And if it doesn't turn out to be a system issue then at least he has ruled encoding out as well.

Comment: It's just a font problem. Not all operating systems go and look for a different font if they encounter a character not in the current one. You can test for yourself by putting a `&#257;` in a title of a HTML file and changing the system settings to use a small font for window titles.

Comment: It is still conceivable (though improbable) that the HTTP headers specify other than UTF-8 encoding and that the occurrences of ā in text have been presented as character and entity references. So the suggestion was not bad.

Comment: Thank you Jukka. Is best to explore every avenue.